# How to install libmaxminddb on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, geolocation, maxmind

The libmaxminddb c libary improves the performance of geo location look ups. But how can I install it on heroku? There is a linux package, but how can this be installed?

Answer (score 0):

just install it in your local virtual environmemt. then do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. When you run your project on heroku next time it will automatically be installed.

Comment: The obvious problem is that libmaxminddb is a c libary and therefore can't be installed as python package.